# Tensorflow serving GPU using REST API and SSL self certificate

Tags: docker, tensorflow, centos7, tensorflow-serving

I am trying to install TensorFlow-gpu with REST API in Centos 7 Docker container.  But I am unable to find an exact procedure for this. Do I need to install following dependencies?

- I have installed cuda 9.0
- cdDNN 7.4
- NCCL 2.x

Comment: I suspect your question will need to be more specific. What step have you got up to, and what exact problem are you experiencing? If you could add your `Dockerfile` to the question, and whether you have a working build, that would help too.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't started yet to build tensorflow serving using GPU. I m in the middle of research stage ~ in this process in every article showing related to Ubuntu installation and m trying to install.in centos 7 .. so I don't have any docker file ..

Hope this may help you and me to get solution .

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use to build a tensorflow-serving-runtime docker image.

```
FROM nvidia/cuda:9.0-cudnn7-runtime-centos7

ARG TF_VERSION=1.9.0

RUN yum install -y  \
    yum-plugin-ovl \
    libgomp \
    ca-certificates \
    zip \
    unzip \
    curl \
        && \
    yum clean all

WORKDIR /usr/
RUN curl -sSL -o /usr/nccl_2.2.13-1-cuda9.0_x86_64.tgz http://some-of-my-net-disk/tensorflow-serving/lib/nccl_2.2.13-1-cuda9.0_x86_64.tgz && \    # Change your way to get nccl library here
    tar -xvf nccl_2.2.13-1-cuda9.0_x86_64.tgz &&\
    rm -f nccl_2.2.13-1-cuda9.0_x86_64.tgz

ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/nccl_2.2.13-1+cuda9.0_x86_64/lib/:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}

# Change your way to get tensorflow_model_server here
WORKDIR /serving
RUN curl -sSL -o /usr/local/bin/tensorflow_model_server http://some-of-my-net-disk/tensorflow-serving/bin/tf-serving-${TF_VERSION}/tensorflow_model_server_gpu-centos &&\
    chmod u+x /usr/local/bin/tensorflow_model_server
```

For me, this worked fine. Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi , thanks for your reply. I have an quick question~ what is the URL that I need to replace for tensorflow serving ?

Comment: I compiled and then uploaded my tensorflow_model_server to a netdisk. You could compile it locally and use COPY to copy it into the image. URL is optional.

Comment: Can you please update me about SSL self-certificate as well?  I have seen ca-certificate in your docker file.